# wxpython boxsizer:problems with dynamically adding items

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, boxsizer

This is driving me nuts.  I usually use Tkinter for gui stuff, but just felt like actually trying to learn wxpython.

I can't for the life of me figure out why when I add items like buttons or static text to a panel, using a boxsizer.  It just seems to cram everything into position (0,0) on the panel called "side"  heres my code.

```
    import wx

    def AddUser():
        ex = wx.App()
        Stylex = wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX
        window = wx.Frame(None, style=Stylex)

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(window, -1)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        """
        LEFT PANEL... Contains Navigation Tree
        """
        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(2,1,5,10) # fgs(int rows, int cols, int vgap, int hgap

        panel = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

        side = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        side.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        multi_btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Batch User Mode")
        multi_btn.SetId(50)

        single_btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Single User Mode")
        single_btn.SetId(25)

        items = [multi_btn,single_btn]

        fgs.AddMany(items)
        vbox.Add(fgs)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        splitter.SplitVertically(panel, side,100)

        """
        SIDE panel...  Contains all widgets
        """
        st = wx.StaticText(side, label="Select a Mode", pos=wx.Point(20,100))
        st.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        def SetMode(event):
            """
            25 returned if Single user mode
            50 returned if Batch user mode
            """
            MODE = event.GetId()

            if MODE == 25:
                try:
                    side.DestroyChildren()
                except: pass

                """
                Problem adding items to the dynamnic changing 'SIDE' panel
                """
                vb = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

                stFName = wx.StaticText(side, id=2,label="First Name:")
                stFName.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
                vb.Add(stFName)
                tcFName = wx.TextCtrl(side, id=4)
                vb.Add(tcFName)

                stLName = wx.StaticText(side,id=6, label="Last Name:")
                vb.Add(stLName)
                tcLName = wx.TextCtrl(side, id=8)
                vb.Add(tcLName)

                vb.Add(side, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)

                side.SetSizer(vb)

                """
                END Problem
                """
            if MODE == 50:
                try:
                    side.DestroyChildren()
                except: pass
                """
                do the same thing as single user creation, except adding listboxes instead of textctrl's
                """
            return

        multi_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, SetMode)
        single_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, SetMode)

        window.SetTitle('User Creation Process')
        window.Centre()
        window.Show(True)

        ex.MainLoop()

    if __name__=='__main__':
        AddUser()
```

Thanks very much for any help... I'm sure its something small that I overlooked, but I would like to understand if its a fundamental problem.

Randy

Comment: I just noticed that you add `side` to `vb` but then set `vb` as `side`'s sizer. So `vb` contains `side` which contains `vb` which contains `side` which contains... My head hurts. What happens if you **don't** add `side` to `vb`?

Comment: hey thanks @acattle I removed the portion `vb.Add(side, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)`  but it didnt seem to help... which tells me I can keep that out of the code?  The whole thing makes my head hurt.  haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default placement. Sizers are NOT for absolute positioning. If you want to, you can do that by passing a position in each widget. If you want your widgets centered on the left, then you'll need to but the vertical BoxSizer inside of a horizontal one and center it. Or you can use a couple of Spacers by using AddSpacer or by just adding a size:

```
mySizer.Add((10, 20), 0, wx.ALL, 5)
```

You can also use the "border" parameter of the Sizer's Add method to control placement to some degree using wx.TOP, wx.BOTTOM, wx.RIGHT or wx.LEFT and giving it the appropriate amount of space. If you are seeing the widgets getting stacked, then you'll need to add a Layout call at the end (probably from the panel or the frame).

**UPDATE**: If you want to swap out panels, I would recommend just hiding and showing them or destroying and creating panels. I wrote up a tutorial on switching panels that might help: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Comment: The OP doesn't use the sizer to set absolute positions. They set an absolute position during the init but they destroy all the panel's children before adding things to the sizer.

Comment: I don't see any positioning in there, but I must be missing it.

Comment: Thanks @MikeDriscoll I don't have it working just yet, but I will definitely look at that tutorial.  Ideally I don't want to use absolute positioning, but I was trying to be fancy and make the StaticText ("st") float to a new position...  I think my next move is to do a bit more tutorial, I just thought it should be as simple as...  `side... which is already there` then you setup your `boxsizer` then you add your `wx.Buttons and wx.StaticTexts to your boxsizer` then your `panel sets the boxsizer`

Comment: you know... its not the end of the world to do an absolute position... I can get it working that way and I am including the mySizers after each... grid i guess you could call it.  I think part of my problem was that I was thinking that I can just add all the items i create into 1 vertical boxsizer without using any horizontal sizers...  instead I think I should have been focusing on putting the items into a grid.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't anything wrong with absolute positioning when you restrict the user's ability to resize the frame. Otherwise, the layout can look kind of odd. I still think you could do what you want with a few spacers and some sizer nesting, but sometimes that can be a pain when you're just learning wxPython.